# Determine app that keeps turning on bluetooth

Tags: applications, bluetooth

I recently got back from a holiday without internet, when I got back heaps of my apps updated and one of them now continuously turns my Bluetooth on. How can I determine which app it is?

I have a rooted Nexus 4 running 4.4.4

Comment: Are you sure an app is turning it on rather than the turning off failing.  I have seen this behaviour from the BT driver stack.  A reboot may help.

Comment: @ifor good idea Ill try rebooting now

Comment: @ifor unfortunately its not the Bluetooth failing to turn off http://youtu.be/usAAU0kEhtg

Answer (score 3):

For me it was [FireChat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FireChat).

With *aSpotCat* you can check which apps have the permission to turn bluetooth on/off.

Comment: Where is bluetooth permission in this app?

Answer (score 3):

Check in Android settings. Security and privacy --> permission--> Turn Bluetooth on. Check which apps you want to keep enabled.